# D3: animate circle between two nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting up to speed with D3 and stumbled upon an excellent script that binds nodes with elliptical arcs. All I am trying (and failing) to achieve is to create a circle and to animate it so that it runs along the arc between two nodes -say between node A and node B.

I think my issue is that I am failing to properly reference the arcs (or 'links'). The piece of code that should be doing this is as follows:

UPDATED --------

```
var pathx = d3.select("path#A->B"),
```

I think I am nearly there. Please find the jsfiddle thus far -the bit that is supposed to animate the circle can be found between the `//animations` and `//end animations` tags. http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/uxy8d9vs/3/

I am basically trying to adapt this working example here: http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8162640

Comment: thiss can help you http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8162640

Comment: `d3.select("path#1")`, `#1` is find element with id of `1`, first, `1` is not a valid id name (spec says it must start with a letter), second, none of your paths have ids.  What were you trying to do there?

Comment: Mark -thank you for your answer. I have amended the script so that (1) all arcs have an ID (checked and is now working) and (2) that all IDs have a valid name (must start with letter). I am still unable to select the path I need, say path with ID "#A->B"... Cyril -thank you very much, this is definitely the script that I need and I have implemented it in my latest jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/uxy8d9vs/3/ . I am very close to finishing this but as you can see above I am still unable to select the arc that I need for the animation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I could not get the animation to work was because the script was running before the dom had finished loading ...

Delaying the animations by a second or so solved the issue. Am surprised D3 cannot handle this better though.